# GRANT SELECT privilege to ALL sequences using one statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I grant the SELECT privilege on all sequences to a user using one statement? Somthing like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON <ALL SEQUENCES???> TO myUser
```

Comment: Also related:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369697/161022
(SELECT won't let you use `nextval`)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.x, you can grant permissions on all sequences in one schema to a role. The [syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html) is

```
GRANT SELECT
ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name
    TO role_name
```

The role can be either a group role or a login role (user name).

Comment: does it apply to future (not yet created) sequences as well, or just the existing ones at the time it is executed?

Comment: @lmsurprenant: Just existing ones, but see [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html).

Answer (score 50):

This will be very useful in the future:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO your_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO your_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA schema_name TO your_user;
```

Comment: what are all privileges means for sequences..?

Comment: Allow to perform this actions: currval(), lastval(), nextval(), setval() and DROP.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer dont worked for me on 9.1. The below sentence did work:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO user;
```

Comment: you need `SELECT, USAGE` if you want to actually modify the sequence

Answer (score 3):

It works in Postgres 13

```sql
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO admin;
```

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres versions lower than 9.0

```
psql -d DBNAME -qAt -c "SELECT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' || relname || ' TO USER;' FROM pg_statio_all_sequences WHERE schemaname = 'public'" | psql -d DBNAME
```

Ref: http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2012/06/11/postgresql-granting-access-to-all-sequences/

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres 15+ there are predefined roles that make it easier to grant useful permissions while setting up your database.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO USER;  
-- SELECT on all tables, views, and sequences. USAGE of all schemas.

GRANT pg_write_all_data TO USER;
-- INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on all tables, views, and sequences. Usage of all schemas.
```