# In PostgreSQL, when granting sequences, can I grant only USAGE instead of both SELECT, USAGE?

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I read answers about granting sequences in PostgreSQL. Generally, they say to grant both SELECT, USAGE. I wonder if I can grant only USAGE. Which one is best practice in granting sequences and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)

SELECT privilege

> For sequences, this privilege also allows the use of the `currval` function.

USAGE privilege

> For sequences, this privilege allows the use of the `currval` **and** `nextval` functions.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the answer is: if you want to allow the usage of `nextval()` you will have to grant the `USAGE` privilege. If you grant USAGE, the SELECT privilege is not needed.

Comment: Very solid. Thank you.